# Built-in air conditioner timer switch wiring

Tags: arduino, switches, relay

I'm not sure if this is specific to this model only, but I was unable to find any standard wiring schematics for [this](https://haier.encompass.com/item/6917392/Haier/AC-7400-01/Timer_-) type of switch.

This is for a [Haier HPAC9M air conditioner unit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AR8YT).

I want to replace the 4 wire timer switch with a standard relay connected to the  GPIO of an Arduino or Pi.

I measured the voltage between the 2 left terminals (2 red wires) and got 120V.
I decided to stop and ask this question before I do anything dangerous.  There are 2 blue wires on the 2 right terminals.

I'm hoping I can grab an off the shelf relay with something like a 5V coil with 120V contacts, but please help me understand the wiring of the switch and what you might suggest I use to do this (relay or not).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out what each of the pins does. Is the switch double pole (two sets of separate contacts) or single pole (one set of contacts)? You can find this out by disconnecting the switch from the device and using a multimeter or other continuity tester to see what connects to what under what circumstances. Are there any labels on the connections? What does this switch actually do precisely?

Once you know this you can consider choosing a relay of appropriate specifications, particularly in terms of the current, number of contacts and type of load being switched.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I like that suggestion - I will go ahead and disconnect the switch to see what each contact is doing.

As for function, the switch is just a knob that, when turned, turns on the AC unit.  But the knob has a timer built in so that after a period of time, the knob will revert back to its original position and turn the AC unit off again.  I think the goal of the switch is just to prevent someone from leaving the unit on indefinitely. 

I'll update once I've checked out the contacts, thanks again!

Comment: I can't seem to answer above (I need "reputation", heh). Brown and blue are the European colour codes for live and neutral (hot/cold, active/negative). Red is the old British colour for live. Since the switch is an active device, I will guess that it has Permanent Live (brown) Switched Live (red) and two neutrals, which are at 0v (a relay thus having no effect) and simply link through and act as a neutral for the switch mechanism. So if this is the case, you'd want to use a N/O relay to connect red and brown. It's possible that the switch is double pole, in which case you'd need a dp relay.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the contacts on the switch - the 2 left wires (brown and red) are 120V wired together, while the 2 blue wires on the right don't seem to measure any voltage when on or off.  I tried hooking up a NO relay to the blue wires, but activating it didn't seem to turn the AC on, even though I heard the relay activate.

I just realized the AC unit has a continuous mode by turning the timer knob all the way to the side, so instead of modifying the timer switch, I am going to set the AC unit to on, and then power the unit through a relay.  So I'll give up on the timer switch and just use a relay connected to the mains to turn the unit on and off.

I ended up finding the [PowerSwitch Tail](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/default.aspx) which looks perfect for my purposes - a relay with 120V contacts, 5VDC coils, and a 16 amperage load rating (AC unit is only rated at 9.3 amps), price a touch high, but safe, so I'm in.

Thanks for all the help, appreciate it!